# penalized cox regression in Python- how to get coefficient and confidence interval after Choosing penalty strength α?

Tags: python, alpha, cox

I am trying to do penalized cox regression in python and to get the coeffecients, I am struggling to get the confidence intervals and would appreciate your help.Running this code , I can get the coefficient for each variable. However, I am struggling to get the P value or confidence interval

I wonder what is the next step to get the P value and confidence interval
Codes are :

```
import warnings

from sklearn.exceptions import ConvergenceWarning

from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

coxnet_pipe = make_pipeline(
    StandardScaler(),
    CoxnetSurvivalAnalysis(l1_ratio=0.9, alpha_min_ratio=0.01, max_iter=100)
)

warnings.simplefilter("ignore", ConvergenceWarning)

coxnet_pipe.fit(Xt, y)

estimated_alphas = coxnet_pipe.named_steps["coxnetsurvivalanalysis"].alphas_
cv = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=0)

gcv = GridSearchCV(
    make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), CoxnetSurvivalAnalysis(l1_ratio=0.9)),
    param_grid={"coxnetsurvivalanalysis__alphas": [[v] for v in estimated_alphas]},
    cv=cv,
    error_score=0.5,
    n_jobs=4).fit(Xt, y)

cv_results = pd.DataFrame(gcv.cv_results_)

best_model = gcv.best_estimator_.named_steps["coxnetsurvivalanalysis"]

best_coefs = pd.DataFrame(
    best_model.coef_,
    index=Xt.columns,
    columns=["coefficient"]
)
```

Comment: Please put your code all in one block. If you want to separate it to make it more organized, do so with empty lines. That way, its organization will be preserved when we copy and paste the code.

Comment: Yes, did the changes